# How to add a conditional line break before a row contains a specific character in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, excel-2016

I have an excel 2016 file including a table like below:

```
ID Name Amount
1   *    500
1   A    300
1   B    200
2   *    250
2   X    150
2   Y    125
2   Z    25
3   *    400
...
```

I want to create a rule to add a line break before each row EXCEPT the very first row who has "Name" value as star character. So my expected output is:

```
ID Name Amount
1   *    500
1   A    300
1   B    200

2   *    250
2   X    150
2   Y    125
2   Z    25

3   *    400
...
```

I could manage to add highlights or so via "Conditional Rule" option, but how can I add a line break? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert a row above *?

Comment: @NareshBhople Yes, i need a blank row before each row includes star character in "Name" column, except the top row tho.

Comment: This may help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517957/insert-a-blank-row-above-a-certain-string-in-excel-vba

Comment: This answer is good and working, just one problem tho. I need to click the "run" button after I download the excel file from the server. Is it a way to automatize it as I need to download the excel file from the server, which will be generated automatically by another program, in the way the blank line already inserted? @NareshBhople

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub insert_row()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'Better use sheet name here as Sheets("ABC") instead of Activesheet
    Dim lastRow as long
    Dim r As Long
    lastRow = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, 2).Offset(0, -1) = 1 Then Exit For 'check if id = 1
        If InStr(ws.Cells(r, 2).Value, Chr(42)) Then ws.Rows(r).Insert
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Naresh, it helped a lot. I've managed to add it as a start-up macro as well.